# How do I make the Bootstrap 5 Carousel slide faster?

Tags: performance, carousel, slide

I don't mean the transition, Im talking about how long each Image is visible.

```
.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Doc says : Add data-bs-interval="" to a .carousel-item to change the amount of time to delay between automatically cycling to the next item.

Answer (score 0):

Doc says : Add `data-bs-interval=""` to a `.carousel-item` to change the amount of time to delay between automatically cycling to the next item.

Comment: Could you add the link to the doc in question please?